# C++: Save information from console, then when reopened, information is still there

Tags: c++

I have a program that saves your favorite games for you onto a list. How would I make it so that if I close the console and reopen it, the list is still there, and all the elements in the array are saved?

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> games;
    vector<string>::iterator iter;

    while(true)
    {
    system("cls");
    string response;
    cout << "\tFavorite Videos Games \n\n";
    cout << "Type 'add' to add a game.\n";
    cout << "Type 'remove' to remove a game.\n";
    cout << "Type 'list' to list all games.\n\n";
    cout << "Type 'quit' to close and save the program.";
    cout << "What would you like to do: ";
    cin >> response;
    cout << endl;

    if ((response == "add") || (response == "remove") || (response == "list"))
    {
        int number;
        string gameName;
        if(response == "add")
        {
            cout << "What is the name of the game you would like to add?\n";
            cout << "Name: ";
            cin >> gameName;
            games.push_back(gameName);
            cout << gameName << " was added to the system.\n\n";
            Sleep(2000);
            continue;
        }
         if(response == "remove")
        {
            vector<string>::iterator linesIn;
            int spacesIn;
            cout << "What game should be deleted?\n\n";
            cout << "All Games:\n-----------\n";
            for(iter = games.begin(); iter != games.end(); ++iter)
            {
                number ++;
                cout << number << ". " << *iter << endl;
            }
            cout << "Number: ";
            cin >> spacesIn;
            spacesIn = spacesIn -1;
            linesIn = games.begin() + spacesIn;
            cout << *linesIn << " was deleted.";
            games.erase(linesIn);
            Sleep(2000);

        }
         if(response == "list")
        {
            cout << "All Games:\n-----------\n";
            for(iter = games.begin(); iter != games.end(); ++iter)
            {
                number ++;
                cout << number << ". " << *iter << endl;
            }
            cout << "\n\nPress any key to continue...";
            getch();
        }

    }
    else if (response == "quit")
        break;
    else
    {
        cout << "\nInvalid action.\n\n";
        Sleep(2000);
        continue;
    }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you save it to file?

Comment: Are you asking how to write and read a file?

Comment: IF thats what I have to do. would that work to save the information?

Comment: @duck sorry i forgot to tag you

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to save it out to file.

Example from http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
   ofstream myfile;
   myfile.open ("example.txt");
   myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
   myfile.close();
   return 0;
}
```

Perhaps add another option called save, and just iterate through the games and add them to a file called "mygames.txt."

Then add an option called "load saved games" and do something like:

```
string line;
ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
if (myfile.is_open()){
while ( getline (myfile,line) ){
    games.push_back(line);
}
myfile.close();
```

Obviously, these are just examples, but I feel it is clear enough that you can take it form here.

Answer (score 1):

Save the information to file.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

else if ( response == "quit") {
    std::ofstream f( "list.txt");
    if( !f) return -1;
    std::vector<std::string> games;
    std::copy( std::istream_iterator<std::string>(f), // copy file content
               std::istream_iterator<std::string>(), games.begin()); // to vector
}
```

On the start of program:

```
int main()
{
    std::ifstream f( "list.txt");
    if( !f) return -1;
    std::copy( istream_iterator<std::string > (f), // copy file content to vector
            std::istream_iterator<std::string > (), std::back_inserter(games));
    //...
```

---

Complete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>   
using namespace std;

int main( int argc, char** argv) {
    fstream f;
    f.open( "list.txt", std::ios::in);
    if (!f) return -1;
    vector<string> games;
    copy( istream_iterator<string > (f), // copy file content to vector
            istream_iterator<string > (), back_inserter(games));
    f.close();
    string response;
    while ( 1) {
        cin >> response;
        if ( ( response == "a")) {
            int number; string gameName;
            cout << "What is the name of the game you would like to add?\n";
            cout << "Name: "; cin >> gameName;
            games.push_back(gameName);
            cout << gameName << " was added to the system.\n\n";
        } else if ( response == "q") {
            f.open( "list.txt", std::ios::out);
            if ( !f) return -1;
            copy( games.begin(), games.end(), // copy from vector to a file
                    ostream_iterator<string > ( f, "\n"));
            f.close();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do i have to #include anything? @lizusek

Comment: @user3444224  yes, I have just indicated what to include